# Exactly which signal was used to track Sisko?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

A continuation of [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/139442/7885) question. In the end of [Waltz episode](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Waltz_(episode))

> Sisko is rescued by Defiant after Defiant received a location or distress call from planet surface. It is said that it was **Gul Dukat's signal**, that Defiant received.

How it is possible?

> Dukat destroyed its own distress-transmitting equipment in the middle of this episode. And since he escaped on-board Federation roundabout, then he must use its communication systems to transmit a location signal. Defiant crew wasn't familiar with events happening on planet's surface. And thus, how did they managed to say, that Dukat signal was used?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How did they find Captain Sisko at the end of the DS9 episode “Waltz?”](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93573/how-did-they-find-captain-sisko-at-the-end-of-the-ds9-episode-waltz?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quote from the [original script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/535.txt) is

> **O'BRIEN:** **(off console)** *Captain. I'm picking up a signal...* (turns in surprise) *It's from Gul Dukat.*

Since the signal was evidently visual in origin (hence O'Brien seeing it on his comms console), presumably it was actually **a written message transmitted on a Federation channel**.

> ["*This is Gul Dukat, your captain is at coordinates x, y, z on the
>   following planet"*]